# xml to dataframe repeating node attr

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to convert a huge .xml file to dataframe. It looks like this (but with millions of <Cli clusters like this one):

```
<Cli Cd="11300000029" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="0202" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="4934.84" v170="4856.16"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="1901" VincME="N">
        <Venc v20="22877.77"/>
    </Op>
</Cli>

<Cli Cd="11400000029" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="0204" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="5000.10"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="1902" VincME="N">
        <Venc v20="32000.22"/>
    </Op>
</Cli>
```

Each <Cli can have several <Op and each <Op can have several <Venc.

Expected result is:

```r
tibble::tribble(
  ~Cd, ~CoobAss, ~CoobRec, ~Mod, ~VincME, ~v165, ~v170, ~v20,
  "11300000029", "0.00", "0.00", "0202", "N", "4934.84", "4856.16", NA,
  "11300000029", "0.00", "0.00", "1901", "N", NA, NA, "22877.77",
  "11400000029", "0.00", "0.00", "0204", "N", "5000.10", NA, NA,
  "11400000029", "0.00", "0.00", "1902", "N", NA, NA, "32000.22"
)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#>   Cd          CoobAss CoobRec Mod   VincME v165    v170    v20     
#>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
#> 1 11300000029 0.00    0.00    0202  N      4934.84 4856.16 <NA>    
#> 2 11300000029 0.00    0.00    1901  N      <NA>    <NA>    22877.77
#> 3 11400000029 0.00    0.00    0204  N      5000.10 <NA>    <NA>    
#> 4 11400000029 0.00    0.00    1902  N      <NA>    <NA>    32000.22
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I can get Cli, Op and Venc in differents dataframes but i couldn't figure it out how to put them all together like that.

## EDIT: CREATING A BIG FILE

In order to performance testing, you can replicate the data to increase file size. Change `n` to desired size:

```
xml = c('
<Cli Cd="11300000029" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="0202" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="4934.84" v170="4856.16"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="1901" VincME="N">
        <Venc v20="22877.77"/>
    </Op>
</Cli>

<Cli Cd="11400000029" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="0204" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="5000.10"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="1902" VincME="N">
        <Venc v20="32000.22"/>
    </Op>
</Cli>
')

n = 3
data = do.call("rbind", replicate(n, xml, simplify = FALSE))

write(data, "xml.xml")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just traverse through all `Venc` nodes and find the attributes for each `Venc` node together with its parent node (i.e. `Op`) and grandparent node (i.e. `Cli`)? The key here is that although you have many `Cli`s, `Op`s or `Venc`s, the tree structure ensures one and only one parent/grandparent for each child. In this regard, we can just do a backward search. Try this:

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

map_dfr(
  html_nodes(xml, xpath = "//Venc"), 
  function(x) c(html_attrs(html_node(x, xpath = "ancestor::Cli")), html_attrs(html_node(x, xpath = "parent::Op")), html_attrs(x))
)
```

Here,  `xml` is an `xml_document` object returned by `xml2::read_xml`.

**Update**

I tested the following code with the specification `n = 1,000,000`, which creates a 424MB XML document. On my laptop, it took about 20 minutes to finish all the computations required.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(tibble)

# xml should be replaced with your `xml_document` object
xml_ls <- as_list(html_nodes(xml, xpath = "//Cli"))

unpack_attrs <- function(x) {
  f <- function(i) {
    attrs <- attributes(i)
    if (length(i) > 0L) i <- list(. = `attributes<-`(i, NULL))
    c(i, `[[<-`(attrs, "names", NULL))
  }
  rbindlist(lapply(x, f), fill = TRUE)
}

recur_unpack_attrs <- function(xml_tree) {
  recur_ <- function(dt, out) {
    init <- dt[, unpack_attrs(.)]
    if ("." != names(init)[[1L]]) {
      out[, names(init) := init]
      return(NULL)
    }
    out[, (names(init)[-1L]) := init[, -1L]]
    recur_(init, out)
  }
  start <- unpack_attrs(xml_tree)
  result <- start[, -1L]
  recur_(start, result)
  as_tibble(result)
}

res <- recur_unpack_attrs(xml_ls)
```

CPU times

```
  user  system elapsed 
971.05  107.61 1150.56
```

Give it a try. Let me know the outcome.

**Second and Last Update**

I reworked most of the code for a stabler performance. I also removed dependency on `rvest`. However, I can't keep doing this forever as I also have other priorities to deal with. Sorry but this is my last update to your question.

```
library(xml2)
library(data.table)
library(tibble)

unpack_attr <- function(xi, i) {
  attrs <- attributes(xi)
  if (length(xi) < 1L || is.null(attrs[["names"]]) ) {
    xi <- list(. = NA)
  } else {
    xi <- list(. = `attributes<-`(xi, NULL))
  }
  c(xi, `[[<-`(attrs, "names", NULL))
}

unpack_attrs <- function(x, ids = NULL) {
  out <- list()
  i <- 1L
  while (i <= length(x)) {
    out[[i]] <- unpack_attr(x[[i]])
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  names(out) <- ids
  rbindlist(out, fill = TRUE, idcol = TRUE)
}

recur_unpack_attrs <- function(xml_tree) {
  out <- unpack_attrs(xml_tree)[, .id := as.character(.I)]
  nms <- names(out)[-1:-2]
  out_nms <- nms
  while (!all(is.na(out[["."]]))) {
    last <- copy(out)
    out <- out[, unpack_attrs(., .id)]
    tmp <- names(out)
    conf <- match(out_nms, tmp, 0L); conf <- conf[conf > 0L]
    if (length(conf) > 0L) tmp[conf] <- paste0(tmp[conf], "_", conf - 2L + length(out_nms))
    out_nms <- c(out_nms, tmp[-1:-2])
    names(out) <- tmp
    out[last, (nms) := mget(paste0("i.", nms)), on = ".id"][, .id := as.character(.I)]
    nms <- names(out)[-1:-2]
  }
  out[rowSums(is.na(out)) < length(out) - 1L, ..out_nms]
}

# replace xml with your xml_document object or "data.xml" the your file path
xml <- read_xml("data.xml")
xml_ls <- as_list(xml_find_all(xml, xpath = "//Cli"))
index <- seq_len(length(xml_ls))
tasks <- split(index, (index - 1L) %/% 50000L)
res <- as_tibble(rbindlist(lapply(tasks, function(task) recur_unpack_attrs(xml_ls[task])), fill = TRUE))
```

The code above works well on a sample xml document consisting of 500,000 replicates (437MB) of the followings:

```
<Cli Cd="11300000029" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="0202" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="4934.84" v170="4856.16"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="1901" VincME="N">
        <Venc v20="22877.77"/>
    </Op>
</Cli>

<Cli Cd="11400000029" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="0204" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="5000.10"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="0201" VincME="N">
        <Venc v165="we000.10"/>
        <Venc v165="we000.10"/>
        <Venc v165="we000.10"/>
    </Op>
    <Op Mod="1902" VincME="N">
        <Venc v20="32000.22"/>
    </Op>
</Cli>
<Cli><Op><Venc v165="400.0"/></Op></Cli>
<Cli></Cli>
<Cli><Venc/></Cli>
<Cli><Venc v165="4343000.10"/><Venc v20="4343000.10"/></Cli>
<Cli>
</Cli>
<Cli><Op><Venc/></Op></Cli>
<Cli Cd="11400000024" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00"/>
<Cli Cd="11400000024" CoobAss="0.00" CoobRec="0.00">
    <Op Mod="4757" VincME="N"/>
</Cli>
```

Performance (it is clear that the conversion from an xml_document object to an R list is the bottleneck, but the run time is still acceptable)

```
> system.time({
+   xml_ls <- as_list(xml_find_all(xml, xpath = "//Cli"))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
1206.36   28.74 1250.89 
> 
> system.time({
+   index <- seq_len(length(xml_ls))
+   tasks <- split(index, (index - 1L) %/% 50000L)
+   res <- as_tibble(rbindlist(lapply(tasks, function(task) recur_unpack_attrs(xml_ls[task])), fill = TRUE))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
 161.03   12.68  175.41
```

Since your xml structure is not well-organised, I have to make several key assumptions:

1. All your data are stored as tag attributes and not as text content (i.e. there is no such thing as `<Cli>blah blah</Cli>`)
2. Each `<OP>` or `<Venc>` must reside in a `<Cli>`. However, it's okay to have tags without attributes (e.g. `<Cli><Op><Venc v165="4343000.10"/></Op></Cli>`) or tags missing a non-`<Cli>` layer (e.g. `<Cli><Venc v165="4343000.10"/></Cli>`).
3. Tags with no attribute will be dropped.
4. The unpacking process starts from the outermost layer (i.e. `<Cli>`) to the innermost layer (i.e. `<Venc>`). Each time a layer is unpacked, new columns will be created based on the attribute names found in that layer. This means that if cases like the following exist, then we will see conflicts.

```
<Cli><Venc v160="333"></Cli>
<Cli><Op><Venc v160="434"></Op></Cli>
```

In the case above, a column named `v160` will be created on unpacking the first `<Cli>` but later there will be another attempt to create the same `v160` column on unpacking that `<Op>` inside the second `<Cli>`. The second `v160` will be given a new name to avoid conflicts.

An output like this just indicates column name conflicts. You have to manually decide how to merge those columns (e.g. `v165` and `v165_8`)

```
# A tibble: 6,000,000 x 10
   Cd          CoobAss CoobRec Mod   VincME v165       v20        v165_8   v170    v20_10  
   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   
 1 11300000029 0.00    0.00    0202  N      NA         NA         4934.84  4856.16 NA      
 2 11300000029 0.00    0.00    1901  N      NA         NA         NA       NA      22877.77
 3 11400000029 0.00    0.00    0204  N      NA         NA         5000.10  NA      NA
```

Last but not least, the default maximum size of R's [pointer protection stack](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/library/base/html/Memory.html) is `50000`. `data.table::rbindlist` pre-allocates pointers to each element of the list before joining them so as to maximise speed. However, that also means we have to do memory management when supplying a large list (with more than 50000 elements) to that function. That's why we need this line `tasks <- split(index, (index - 1L) %/% 50000L)` to turn binding a large list into small tasks that do not exceed the limit.

If the code fails again this time, then you probably have to ask others for help.
Sorry about that.

Comment: It did work with the reprex. But it's extremely slow tho :( I hit it yesterday on a 400mb file and it's been working overnight and hasn't completed yet. Is there any alternative to {purrr} in this case that won't take forever?

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda How about `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(html_nodes(xml, xpath = "//Venc"), function(x) as.list(c(html_attrs(html_node(x, xpath = "ancestor::Cli")), html_attrs(html_node(x, xpath = "parent::Op")), html_attrs(x)))), fill = TRUE)`. This one should be faster than the above. But I think the bottleneck here should be the `html_nodes` part. Need more data to test.

Comment: 6 hours into it and still running. That's frustrating.

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda I need more data to test if you want further speed improvement. Do you mind sharing a larger dataset that contains, for instance, 20 `Cli`s?

Comment: I've got the following error with the file: Error in `[.data.table`(out, , `:=`((names(init)[-1L]), init[, -1L])) : 
  Supplied 175 items to be assigned to 191 items of column 'Mod'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: I'll have to figure out what's in the original file's structure that wasn't replicated in the reprex.

Comment: There's some <Cli alone (doesn't has any <op or <venc beneath them). Would it impact?

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda Yes, that is the reason why this code cannot run properly, Check my second update.

Comment: Man, it worked beautifully! There's a lot of sintax you used that i don't understand so i wouldn't came to an answer to this problem without your help. So thank you very much!